# Initial states problem with ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem:
What can we say about the funcions $t_0 \rightarrow y(t,t_0,y_0)$ and $ y_0 \rightarrow y(t,t_0,y_0)$   where $y(t,t_0,x_0)$ is the solution of the following Caychy problem
$$y'(t)=f(t,y(t)),  \\ y(t_0)=y_0$$ with $f$ is gloally lipcshitz.
Are they are differentiabl! or invertible ? 
Thank you.

Comment: It is the flow of the ODE, usually the IC are more emphatically separated as $\phi(t;t_0,y_0)$. And what is the connection of $x_0$ and $y_0$? As it is, your question is too broad, the answer is "All the properties of an ODE solution where the right side is Lipschitz".

Comment: By Picard-Lindelöf,  the function in question is injective.

Comment: I'm loking for the properties of such a functions. the first is $t_0 \rightarrow y(t,t_0,y_0)$ and the second is  $t_0 \rightarrow y(t,t_0,y_0)$ . Are they invertible? and in which domain?. Thank you.

Comment: I added the question. Thank you guys.